# Half range Fourier sine series of cos(x) on 0 < x < $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> **a)** Find the half range Fourier sine series of $\cos(x)$ on $\displaystyle 0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$.
>
> **b)** Use this extension to show that $\displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2m+1)}{4(2m+1)^{2}-1}(-1)^{m} = \frac{\pi}{8\sqrt2}$

For **a)** I have solved it by using:

$$b_n = \frac{2}{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(x)\sin(2nx) \mathrm{d}x $$

So, $$b_n = \frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(x)\sin(2nx) \mathrm{d}x $$
I solved $b_n$ by using the formula for $\sin A \cos B = \frac{1}{2}(\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)$.

So I got,  $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(2nx+x)\sin(2nx-x) dx $$

This gives: $$\frac{\sin(\pi n)+1}{2n+1}+\frac{1-\sin(\pi n)}{2n-1}$$

After simplifying, I got:
$$b_n = \frac{4}{\pi}\frac{-\sin(\pi n)+2n}{4n^{2}-1} $$

This is where my problem is. I'm thinking that what I get from part **a)** should be similar to part **b)**, but with my $n=2m+1$. From part b), it seems the answer should be:
$$\frac{n\sin(\frac{\pi n}{2})}{4n^{2}-1}$$
Can someone tell me where I went wrong with part **a)**? Thanks.

Comment: Check substitution $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ after integration.

Comment: I just looked at it and I made a typo, substitution was already done when I got $\frac{sin(\pi n)+1}{2n+1}+\frac{1-sin(\pi n)}{2n-1}$. Is it still wrong?@MyGlasses

Comment: Why don't you continue your solution.? $\sin n\pi=0$

Comment: If $sin(\pi n) = 0$, we get $\frac{4n}{4n^{2}-1}$. But this still isn't what part b) is implying? @MyGlasses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$b_n = \dfrac{8n}{\pi(4n^{2}-1)} $ and
$$\cos x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{8n}{\pi(4n^{2}-1)}\sin 2nx$$
set $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$:
$$\cos \dfrac{\pi}{4}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{8n}{\pi(4n^{2}-1)}\sin n\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$
if $n=2m$ then $\sin n\dfrac{\pi}{2}=0$. if $n=2m+1$ then $\sin n\dfrac{\pi}{2}=(-1)^m$ thus
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \dfrac{8(2m+1)}{\pi(4(2m+1)^{2}-1)}(-1)^m$$

Comment: oh so we eliminate $sin(n \pi)$ in $\frac{4}{\pi}\frac{-sin(\pi n)+2n}{4n^{2}-1} $ to get $\frac{4}{\pi}\frac{2n}{4n^{2}-1}$?  @MyGlasses

Comment: But, why your question begin from $n=0$.? check your main question.

Comment: It says m=0...Is it not suppose to be? Could be a typo. @MyGlasses

Comment: Perhaps. The main definition of half range Fourier sine series is began from 1.

Comment: My prof mentioned how the series starts at 0 for cosine when its 2m+1 and it starts at 1 when its 2m-1. Maybe thats why? @MyGlasses

Comment: Yes. It's. With begining $m=1$ we ignore the first term, so we have to start by $m=0$. OK.